# Android EntryAdapter crashing on super()

Tags: android, multithreading

I'm trying to pull some information from the web in my app. Network interaction can't be done in the MainActivity, so I've got an instance of Runnable going to handle this. However, since I started that, I've been getting a null pointer exception. LogCat is pointing me at these chunks of code:

```
public CelebrityEntryAdapter(Activity context, List<CelebrityEntry> list) {
    super(context, R.layout.activity_celebrity, list);
    this.context = context;
    this.list = list;
}
```

and here (at the "adapter = new CelebrityEntryAdapter..." line):

```
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    context = this;
    filterText = (EditText) getView().findViewById(R.id.search_box);
    filterText.addTextChangedListener(filterTextWatcher);
    new Thread(new Runnable(){
        public void run()
        {
            try {
                adapter = new CelebrityEntryAdapter(context.getActivity(), populate());
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            setListAdapter(adapter);

            filterTextWatcher = new TextWatcher() {

                public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
                }

                public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
                        int after) {
                }

                public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before,
                        int count) {
                    adapter.getFilter().filter(s);
                }
            };
        }
    }).start();
}
```

What do you think?

EDIT:

Here's logcat:

05-01 18:49:36.391: E/AndroidRuntime(1468): FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-109
05-01 18:49:36.391: E/AndroidRuntime(1468): java.lang.NullPointerException
05-01 18:49:36.391: E/AndroidRuntime(1468): at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.init(ArrayAdapter.java:310)
05-01 18:49:36.391: E/AndroidRuntime(1468): at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.(ArrayAdapter.java:153)
05-01 18:49:36.391: E/AndroidRuntime(1468): at edu.Drake.doppelganger.CelebrityEntryAdapter.(CelebrityEntryAdapter.java:31)
05-01 18:49:36.391: E/AndroidRuntime(1468): at edu.Drake.doppelganger.CelebritiesFragment$1.run(CelebritiesFragment.java:60)
05-01 18:49:36.391: E/AndroidRuntime(1468): at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)

Here's populate():

```
public List<CelebrityEntry> populate() throws IOException {
    List<CelebrityEntry> list = new ArrayList<CelebrityEntry>();
    HttpGet httppost = new HttpGet("http://www.ethanclevenger.com/MirrorMe/celebrity-master.txt");
    HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
    HttpEntity ht = response.getEntity();
    BufferedHttpEntity buf = new BufferedHttpEntity(ht);
    InputStream is = buf.getContent();
    BufferedReader r = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
    String name;
    String url;
    while ((name = r.readLine()) != null) {
        url = r.readLine();
        Log.v(url, url);
        list.add(new CelebrityEntry(name, url));
    }
    return list;
}
```

Sorry for the awful logcat formatting - trying to figure that out. I've been able to log both "url" and "name" from "populate()" - it's definitely retrieving it.

For good measure, here's the constructor:

```
public CelebrityEntry(String name, String pic) {
    this.name = name;
    this.pic = pic;
}
```

Comment: where is your logcat?

Comment: Where is the definition of populate()? Maybe it's returning null value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whatever you think `context.getActivity()` is appears to be returning `null`, as that is the only source of a `NullPointerException` in the `init()` method of `ArrayAdapter`.

Beyond that:

- Please do not attempt to modify the UI from a background thread, as you are doing here (pro tip: use `AsyncTask`)
- Please do not just blindly ignore an exception, such as you are doing with the `IOException`

Comment: Thanks for the tips. I'm working on implementing an AsyncTask. I'm still getting this null pointer error - the ArrayAdapter needs both a context and the list. The context is the ListFragment that the offending code is contained in. How can I get that context to pass into my adapter?

Comment: @EthanC: "The context is the ListFragment that the offending code is contained in" -- no, because `ListFragment` does not inherit from `Context`. From the code you have presented, it is unclear why `getActivity()` would be returning `null`. It may be tied into however you are creating the fragment.

Comment: After looking at my code, I found that the parameters were poorly named - it does in fact need a Fragment and the list. So reworded question - how can I get the fragment from within my async task?

Comment: @EthanC: Make the `AsyncTask` be a regular inner class of the fragment, in which case you access the fragment as `CelebritiesFragment.this`. Or, if you want the `AsyncTask` to be a static inner class or separate public class, pass in the `Fragment` via the constructor.